# How to Change Woocommerce Order Tracking Status Text in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, woocommerce

So, I need to Change The Order tracking status on account order page in woocommerce, I need to Change this text , its included on `plugin/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/view-order.php`

I need to change the `'Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce'` when I change it from `view-order.php` nothing changed, please help

```
<p>
<?php
    /* translators: 1: order number 2: order date 3: order status */
    printf(
        __( 'Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>'
    );
?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a copy of plugin/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/view-order.php
and place in yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/ 
any edit in this file will work

```
<p><?php
    /* translators: 1: order number 2: order date 3: order status */
    printf(
        __( 'Your Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>'
    );
?>
```

[image: Order title change]